# How to redirect welcome page using abstract controller class in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, javabeans, java-ee-7, servletcontextlistener

I try to do multipage form handling through abstract wizzard form controller. But in URL shows http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/ like this. Could not map the WelcomePage.jsp file.
My dispatcher servlet is this

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" />

<bean name="/WelcomePage" class="com.mkyong.common.controller.WelcomeController" />

<bean  class="com.mkyong.common.controller.UserController" >

    <property name="pages">
        <list>
        <!-- follow sequence -->
        <value>Page1Form</value> <!-- page1 -->
        <value>Page2Form</value> <!-- page2 -->
        <value>Page3Form</value> <!-- page3 -->
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="com.mkyong.common.validator.UserValidator" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Register User.properties for validation error message -->
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="User" />
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <property name="prefix">
         <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
      </property>
      <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
     </property>
</bean>
```

And my controller code is here mentioned . If I run my project shows warning 
 No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'

```
public class WelcomeController extends AbstractController{

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView("WelcomePage");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Spring MVC, ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping use convention to map requested URL to Controller (convention over configuration). It takes the Class name, remove the ‘Controller’ suffix if exists and return the remaining text, lower-cased and with a leading “/”.

in your case, you do not have any controller mapped with "/" url, so for accedding to your welcome page you must use : http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/welcome